# An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, entity-framework

I have an assignment due tomorrow and I am slowly losing my mind. Some help would be appreciated.

I keep getting the response -

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException'
>   occurred in EntityFramework.SqlServer.dll

Additional information: Execution Timeout Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

Additional information: One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

Below is both my app.configs

CONSOLE APP.CONFIG

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <configSections>
      <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
    </configSections>
          <startup>

  <connectionStrings>

    <add
    name="VoteWithDEV"
    connectionString="Data Source=k2mmbsouh0.database.windows.net;
    Initial Catalog=VoteWithDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=patrickmcmu11an;;Password=Jordan123"
    providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>

    <appSettings>
     <add key="ConnectionStringName" value="VoteWithDEV"/>
    </appSettings>


</startup>
```

DATA APP.Config

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<configSections>
    <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" requirePermission="false"/>
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="mssqllocaldb"/>
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
    <add
   name="VoteWithDEV"
   connectionString="Data Source=k2mmbsouh0.database.windows.net;
        Initial Catalog=VoteWithDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password"
   providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
      <add key="ConnectionStringName" value="VoteWithDEV"/>
    </appSettings>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Your computer can't reach the database.  There might be nothing wrong with your code.  Where is the server `k2mmbsouh0.database.windows.net` physically located?  Can you reach it via telnet on port 1433?

Comment: For your own privacy, please redact your credentials.

Comment: Based on the URL of the server, I assume this is an Azure SQL Database. Have you set up the firewall correctly in Azure?

Answer (score 3):

Add `Connect Timeout=90` in your `connectionString`.

```
connectionString="Data Source=k2mmbsouh0.database.windows.net;
        Initial Catalog=VoteWithDEV;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=username;Password=password;Connect Timeout=90 "
```

Answer (score 1):

Try SQL Management Studio to check if you can connect. I suspect that the server is down/unreachable.

Answer (score 0):

i faced with this error when SQL server is unreachable.
for checking :

**Win + R -> services.msc -> find out Sql Server [instance name] -> right click on it and click Start.**

if that not works using **SQL server repair solution** :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/install-windows/repair-a-failed-sql-server-installation?view=sql-server-2017